# Индикатор загрузки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как красиво (правильно) организовать индикатор загрузки на странице во время выполнения асинхронных запросов?
Сейчас придумал так: беру гифку, начало загрузки - показываем гифку модально на все окно. Загрузка и/или обработка ответа завершена - скрываем гифку.
Но насколько это правильно, красиво, хорошо - я не знаю.

Под модальным индикатором на все окно, я подразумеваю - маленькую гифку крутящуюся в центре окна в то время как все остальное затемненно

Comment: Модальный индикатор на всё окно? Смеётесь? Начало загрузки - показываем индикатор. Загрузка и/или обработка ответа завершена - скрываем индикатор.

Comment: @Other У меня будут обновляться данные всей таблицы, таблицы - на все окно. И нужно или поверх контейнера с таблицой повесить индикатор или модальное окно) "Начало загрузки - показываем индикатор. Загрузка и/или обработка ответа завершена - скрываем индикатор." - именно это я и имел ввиду.

Comment: Блокировать весь интерфейс стоит в редких случаях. Сохраняйте в очередь действия пользователей, отвлеките их котиками/грудью_младой_девы, но не дайте им почувствовать полное ожидание. А так - принцип просто и гениален (см. первый комментарий).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вы верно рассуждаете. Но вместо того, что бы блокировать во весь экран, можно блокировать соответствующий блок (таблицу).

```js
function asyncRequest(callback) {
  // асинхронная операция, например, ajax-запрос
  setTimeout(callback, 2000);
}

// событие при клике на кнопку
$('.load').click(function() {
    var $preloader = $(this).parent().find('.modal__preloader');
    $preloader.show(); // показываем прелоадер
    asyncRequest(function() {
      $preloader.hide(); // после загрузки данных, скрываем 
    });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  background: #333;  
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative; 
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.modal__preloader {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  top: 0; 
  z-index: 999; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: visible; 
  background: #333 url('http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
  <button class="load">load</button>
  <div class="modal__preloader"></div>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <button class="load">load</button>
  <div class="modal__preloader"></div>
</div>
```